Ternary Nonhomogeneous Diophantine Equation
The known ternary Diophantine equation is as follows
\begin{align*}
(1 - 2X) (X^2 - X + Y^2) + 2 Z^3=0.
\end{align*}
This inhomogeneous ternary Diophantine equation has two singular points, and these two singular points are also rational points.
$(X_1,Y_1,Z_1)=(0,0,0)$,$(X_2,Y_2,Z_2)=(1/2,a,0)$
The computer shows that there are many rational number points on this surface.
We know that Pythagorean numbers can be constructed from rational points, but I am not sure about cubic numbers.
Given these singular solutions, can we construct new solutions?
Or does the construction require knowledge of elliptic curves?
I have an idea that a construction similar to elliptic curve addition can be used to make two points into a new point. However, I don't know how to transform it.

What exactly do you mean by "transforming it" ?

Embedding a surface into a parameterized elliptic curve using birational transformation. @AnuradhaNarasimhan

If you have singular points it is not question of elliptic curves.

You don't say if you want integral solutions, or rational ones but I'll assume you're asking for the latter.
This is a rational surface, just project away from the singular point to parametrise it. One should maybe expect this -- smooth cubic surfaces are unirational, and singular cubic surfaces are "mostly" unirational. More precisely, let $S \subset \mathbb{A}^3$ be the surface cut out by your equation $(1−2X)(X^2−X+y^2)+2Z^3$ and consider the rational map
$$ S \to \mathbb{A}^2 : (X,Y,Z) \mapsto \left( \frac{2X -1}{2Z}, \frac{2Y + 1}{2Z} \right)$$
This rational map is in fact birational over $\mathbb{Q}$, and its inverse is given as
$$ (s,t) \mapsto \left( \frac{s^3 + 2s^2t + st^2 - 1}{2(s^3 + st^2 - 1)} , \frac{s^3 - st^2 - 1}{2(s^3 + st^2 - 1)}, \frac{st}{s^3 + st^2 - 1} \right)$$
In particular, every rational solution to your equation is of the above form for some $(s,t) \in \mathbb{Q}^2$ except for some density zero set (lies on a Zariski closed).

Very beautiful solution! Could you please recommend some literature on related constructions?

It depends on your background, the theory of surfaces even over $\mathbb{C}$ gets quite involved. There is a very beautiful book by Beauville called "complex algebraic surfaces".
